# When adding data to the array it says System.IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, bounds

When adding a data to an array I keep getting the error 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' the Array is declared to bound of 200 and at the data I'm trying to add is at 6 + 1, 6 is the variable count, in the code.

```
Public Class FormEvents
Dim ArrayEvents(200) As String
Dim Count As Integer
Private Sub FormEvents_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Events As String = "C:\Users\Andrew prince\Desktop\Education\College\Computing\Controlled assesment\Program\Program files\Events.txt"
    Dim ObjReader As New StreamReader(Events)
    ArrayEvents = ObjReader.ReadLine().Split(",")
    UpdateInfo()
    ObjReader.Close()
    TxtEventNo.Enabled = False
    BtnAdd.Enabled = False
End Sub

Sub UpdateInfo()
    TxtEventNo.Text = ArrayEvents(Count)
    TxtEventType.Text = ArrayEvents(Count + 1)
    TxtEventDistance.Text = ArrayEvents(Count + 2)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNext.Click
    Count = Count + 3
    checkInfo()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnPrev_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrev.Click
    Count = Count - 3
    checkInfo()
End Sub
Sub Createvent()
    Dim eventNo As String
    eventNo = Count / 3
    TxtEventNo.Text = eventNo
    TxtEventDistance.Text = ""
    TxtEventType.Text = ""
    BtnNext.Enabled = False
    BtnPrev.Enabled = False
    BtnAdd.Enabled = True
End Sub
Sub checkInfo()
    If Count <= 0 Then Count = 0
    If ArrayEvents(Count) = "" Then Createvent() Else UpdateInfo()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
    If TxtEventDistance.Text.Length > 0 And TxtEventType.Text.Length > 0 Then AddToArray()
End Sub
Sub AddToArray()
    ArrayEvents(Count) = TxtEventNo.Text
    ArrayEvents(Count + 1) = TxtEventType.Text 'error occurs here in the code
    ArrayEvents(Count + 2) = TxtEventDistance.Text
    Enable()
End Sub
Sub Enable()
    BtnAdd.Enabled = False
    BtnNext.Enabled = True
    BtnPrev.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You *declared* an array with 201 elements.  You *replaced* it with an array that has however many words in a string.  Which was obviously less than 7.  If you want to add elements to a collection object then never use an array.  Use a List(Of String).

Answer (score 0):

ArrayEvents is probably no longer 200 in length after you set it in the load method to:

```
ArrayEvents = ObjReader.ReadLine().Split(",")
```